# Base64 Images converting - why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, base64

I have a list of png's I'm referencing in my css like so:

```
.nav-questions:before {
        background: url('../../../assets/images/nav-icons/question-list-icon-grey.png') no-repeat;
        width: 25px;
        height: 19px;
    }
```

Some of the images render and some do not and I can only put this down to seeing differences within developer tools. The images that do render, have base64 encoding but how is this possible or why aren't the other images rendering?

See screenshot examples:

Base64 
[image]

Non base64
[image]

Comment: @Kaiido Can you be more specific please

Comment: Your images need to be served. The ones that render are hard-coded in Base64, so this works. The files that need to be fetched are blocked because you use a local path instead of a server.

Comment: Jeremy - why not creating an answer on that? ;o)

Comment: @JeremyThille That's what I don't understand - all the images are on my local machine and referenced the same way above in my css?

Comment: @Kai good idea, I did so :)

Comment: Instead of images, please post the css code...

Answer (score 2):

The images are physically present, but that's not how you request them. When you develop a website, the browser connects to a server, and that server sends assets : HTML pages, CSS files, and images. Browsers don't allow direct access to the user's file system, that would be a terrible security flaw. They only access whatever resource the server is willing to send. So you need to set up a server and connect to it via `localhost:port` in your browser. The server will then serve the images (you'll have to write this part as well, of course).

Comment: Right so I'm building a react js application and can we debate that the images are being served through my local host as all other images render fine? Absolutely baffled.

Comment: I didn't get that. Why are you baffled?

Comment: I have a server running at http://localhost:3001/ ... requesting other images throughout the application has no issues but for these I have no idea why. The other images that render normally do not have the base64 code added to the url? It's strange...

Comment: Oh so you have a server running?? So why did you set an absolute URL Like `C:/Users/Documents/etc.` ? The URL has to be relative to the server, like `/assets/images`. Check your Network tab, it says that the images can't be found.

Comment: It's showing like that because of developer tools I assume? See my code example in my initial question - that's exactly how they are being referenced.

Comment: The path you use is `/Users/jordyvialoux/documents/development/runway/etc.` So I know your name is Jordy Vialoux, so you know there's something wrong with your code. You use an absolute path through your personal documents.

Comment: I think you're missing the code above: background: url('../../../assets/images/nav-icons/question-list-icon-grey.png') no-repeat;

That's how I'm referencing

Comment: Indeed. It looks like the relative path is being interpreted into an absolute path, but really I have no idea why :/

Comment: haha exactly why I'm having the issue zzz - joys of development!!